# Замена последовательности одинаковых символов одним

Tags: php

Взываю о помощи. Мне нужно заменить последовательность абсолютно любых одинаковых символов одним этим символом. Пример: вход -

```
'jamttphjjjj  aa...,.--'
```

выход -

```
'jamtphj a.,.-'
```

У меня есть только РНР5. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Тут, скорее всего, надо проходиться в цикле по строке, запоминая текущий символ и сравнивая со следующим. Если разные - просто пишем символ в новую строку (результат), если одинаковые - то проходим дальше, не записывая в результат.

Comment: А что делать, если будет, например, слово "**button**"? На выходе же будет слово с ошибкой.

Comment: @Deonis, так задачу же не привели.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: Плохо знаю регэкспы, не знал, что так можно. Основывался на словах с какого-то форума, что регэкспы так не умеют. Своей головой не подумал)